# Changing URL in webview after X seconds

Tags: c#, mysql, awesomium

I have a traffic exchange website and now I started a C# project, an automated software for the traffic exchange.
Managed to connect to the MySQL server, retrieve data but I have a big issue.

First, here is the code:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            LoadUrls();
         }



public void LoadUrls()
        {
        try
            {
           string MyConnection2 = "******************";
           string Query = "select * from ******* where status = 1 AND credits > 5 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
            MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
            MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);             
              MyConn2.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader DR = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (DR.Read())
                {

                    string WebURL = Convert.ToString(DR.GetValue(*));
                    string WebSurfSeconds = Convert.ToString(DR.GetValue(*));

                    webControl1.Source = new Uri(WebURL);

                    int result = Convert.ToInt32(WebSurfSeconds);
                    int sec_to_mil = result * 1000;


                    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
                    timer1.Interval = sec_to_mil; // in miliseconds
                    timer1.Start();

                }
            }
            MyConn2.Close();
        }
catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

     }


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadUrls();
        }
```

The code does what a traffic exchange should, but only for a limited time.

About the code : 
Take's a random website out of the database, change the url of the webview ( awesomium ) and after X second re-run this command by timer1.

For the first 3-4 websites is all good and then goes crazy. By crazy I mean, even if the counter should re-run the command after 60 seconds he does it in 2-3 seconds. When this happens it's all gone. There is no going back.

Any ideas what could cause it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting up a new timer every time a row is read? That's probably what's causing your problem. Move your timer init to Form1() so you only do it once. You can change the INTERVAL based upon the row you've read, but you don't want a NEW timer every time (I assume).

Comment: As @MichaelTodd states, you should not `new` up a timer every time. It is never going to stop unless specifically told to do so. It will also never get garbage collected because you subscribed an event to it. As long as that event is there, it will always be running and in memory.